# Using data between javascript and Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made some searches but didn't get exactly what I need. What I need is: I want to get some data generated in the client side javascript, make some manipulations on them in the server side Node.js, then return them back to javascript side. what is the simplest way to do this ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX).

Comment: did you do any research

Comment: @Alex: I found a lot of specific information and didn't know where to start from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simpliest way is to use socket.io

```
Your_project_path$ npm install socket.io
```

Server-side.js :

```
var http = require('http');
var io = require('socket.io');

httpServer = http.createServer();
httpServer.listen(8080);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(httpServer);
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

    // Receive data
    socket.on('my-data', function(data){

         // Do something with your data

         // Send modified data
         socket.emit('my-modified-data', modified_data);
    });
});
```

Client-side.js

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

// Send your data
socket.emit('my-data', {
     data-1 : 'something',
     data-2 : 'something'
});

// Receive your modified data
socket.on('my-modified-data', function(modified-data){

     // Do something with your new data
});
```

Client-side.html

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="client-side.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you!
You deserve upvoting and accepting your answer.

Answer (score -1):

[REST.](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/whatisrest.html)

In your client side you receive the data, modify it, send back to the server and to whatever you want.

Comment: I didn't down vote but this is more worthy as a comment and not an answer, to be honest the question is of poor quality and should be expanded on or removed as it demonstrates little to no research from the author.